# Reading HTML File in .NET with css/javascript comments

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load an HTML document into an `XDocument` in C# and running into issues with comments in `<style>` tags and `<script>` tags. Specifically, there's comments that contain `<` characters, so the `XDocument` throws errors complaining about those containing illegal names.

Here's my C# code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

And (a portion) of my html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="..."/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<style type="text/css">
/*! 
 * Copyright 2012,2013 --- <example@gmail.com> 
...
```

The thing I can think of so far is opening it as a string and wrapping the css/javascript in CDATA tags (using regex), but I was hoping there was an easier way

Comment: I realize the document is supposed to be XHTML, but loading HTML with an XML parser sounds like self-inflicted injury. Have you surveyed the .NET HTML parser tools?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [ryascl](/users/207291/ryascl)'s comment above - a better fit for your problem domain would be an HTML parser, not an XML parser. I haven't used any myself in a while, but here are a couple that a search turned up:

[Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com)

[A managed wrapper for the HTML Tidy library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17124/A-managed-wrapper-for-the-HTML-Tidy-library)

[Chilkat .NET HTML Conversion](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/HtmlToXmlDotNet.asp) - this *converts* to XML, but *parses* HTML

Relevant SE and Wikipedia links:

[C# library for parsing HTML?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/c-library-for-parsing-html)

[Comparison of HTML parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers)